# C# Data Entry Threading From server response event

Tags: c#, multithreading, data-entry

I have a functioning program that will calls for specific data from server, then when data is recieved it parses the data to add to the correct database row. the call when recieved data is landed is as followed:

```
public void AddData(string data)
    {
        if (this.ResponseData.InvokeRequired)
            BeginInvoke(new AddDataDelegate(AddData), new object[] { data });
        else
        {
             //sets new event args and object to run method
            object sender = new object();
            DoWorkEventArgs e = new DoWorkEventArgs(data);
            //Calls the parsing and correct data row input
            DataUpdate(data);
            SystemGrid.Update();
        }    

    }
```

My parsing coding is as followed:

```
private void DataUpdate(string e)
    {
        string[] data = e.ToString().Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if(data[0] == "[Q]")
        {
            int rowindex = 0;
            if(data[2] == "ATQuoteFieldLastPrice")
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in SystemGrid.Rows)
                {
                    if (data[1] == Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                    {
                        rowindex = Row.Index;
                        break;
                    }



                }

                SystemGrid.Rows[rowindex].Cells[5].Value = data[3];
            }




        }
        if(data[0] == "[B]")
        {
            int index = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in SystemGrid.Rows)
            {

                if (Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == data[1])
                {
                    index = Row.Index;

                    break;

                }

            }
            SystemGrid.Rows[index].Cells[9].Value = data[3];
            SystemGrid.Rows[index].Cells[10].Value = data[4];
            SystemGrid.Rows[index].Cells[11].Value = data[5];
            SystemGrid.Rows[index].Cells[12].Value = data[6];
            SystemGrid.Rows[index].Cells[13].Value = data[7];
        }
    }
```

when a timer goes off it sends for a set of data that arrives string by string. 
first set finishes within 30 seconds. then the second set fires off, this takes 2min 20secs - 2min 30secs to finish. this second set has over 300,000 lines of data to go through. and will change on ever second set depending on what data changed on the server.

the third set finishes within 30secs
the fourth same as the second set
fith same as first.
6th set same as second set.

total time to update is right at 8 min give or take a little. 
is there a way to thread the ADD(data) event safely, without data loss.

i've tried a backgroundworker, but the speed at which the data comes in is to fast so with that route it took the same time to finish. if tried a thread loop between 2 backgrounders, but continuely lost data.

is there a way to possibly thread pool this event upon landing, without loosing data. As the data will consistently coming in.

I am trying to get cut at least 3min of data processing. 
so by the time the next update comes out the program is ready to fire again.

Comment: response from the server for sets 1,3,5 is [Q],symbol,datatype,value    while sets 2,4,6 look like this [B],date,value,value,value,value,value

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve]. Right now it's very difficult to understand what you're asking. If you made it easy you would have had a number of answers by now.

Comment: in the add data if i switch from calling the function to calling this.backgroundworker.RunAsync(data);    Program goes into break mode from micolib exception. When I try to create new thread to run DataUpdate function, UI thread exits.  All im asking how land continuous new thread to run Dataupdate upon landing the response in AddData, without loosing UI thread.

Comment: is there a way to land the AddData function into a Thread Pool.

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful. I don't know what you mean by "UI thread exits", or "land continuous new thread", or "without loosing UI thread".